# jQuery Form Validation Works Only Once Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

User must select at least one checkbox option. If valid > submit form. Only works once. If the user will check and uncheck the box, and submit again, the form will submit empty.

```
$('#submit-button').on('click', function() {
    $('input:checkbox').each(function() {
        if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#submit-error').html('Plase select at least one option!');
            return false;
        } else {
            $('#my-form').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT: this form is inside a Modal window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#submit-button').on('click', function() {
    if(!$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length)
    {
        $('#submit-error').html('Plase select at least one option!');
        return false;
    }
    else 
       $('#my-form').submit();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It is still not working. I should add that this form is inside a Modal window if that makes any difference.

Comment: Actually, I did have a typo in there and your code is working! Thank you!